# Cannot connect from android emulator to API in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, react-native

I have an API in my docker container. I create it by docker-compose like here:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  stocqres.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}stocqresapi
    network_mode: host
    container_name: "stocqres"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Stocqres.Api/Dockerfile
    links:
      - mongoDb
      - sqlServer
    ports:
      - '443:443'

  sqlServer:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    network_mode: host
    container_name: "sqlServer"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: Your_password123
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
    ports:
      - '20:1433'
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    volumes:
      - /var/opt/mssql
      - ./scripts/SqlServer:/usr/src/app
    command: bash -c "sh entrypoint.sh & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr"

  mongoDb:
    image: mongo:latest
    network_mode: host
    container_name: "mongodb"
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'

volumes:
  mongodata:
```

I have also a react-native app, but when I am trying to connect to my API called stocqres.api from an android emulator it cannot connect. I tried to connect by 10.0.2.2:433, also by my local computer ip: 192.168.1.100. Every time axios client throws me an error "Network Error" with error code 0.

It is my axios config:

```
const client = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://192.168.0.100:443/api',
  responseType: 'json',
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

and here is a code, responsible to call an API:

```
export function login (username, password) {
    return {
    type: types.LOGIN,
    payload: {
        request: {
        url: '/tokens/create',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            command:{
                Username: username,
                Password:password
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't got any idea where is the problem. I assume that the problem is related to docker network settings. I was looking for a solution, but nothing helps. Maybe you will have some idea, where is an issue?

Thank you very much for you attention and for help.